# Decrypting openssl aes-256-cbc using node.js?

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I'm encrypting my file on the command line using:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -e -in test.env -out test.env.encrypted
```

and then trying to decrypt on node.js with:

```
crypto    = require('crypto')
algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'
password  = 'test'

fs = require 'fs'
decrypt = (text) ->
  decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password)
  dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8')
  dec

file = fs.readFileSync './test.env.encrypted', 'utf-8'

console.log decrypt file
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Bad input string at Decipher.update (crypto.js:168:26) at decrypt (/Users/h/tmp/encrypt_test/test.coffee:10:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/h/tmp/encrypt_test/test.coffee:16:13) at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/h/tmp/encrypt_test/test.coffee:1:1) at Module._compile (module.js:569:30) at Object.CoffeeScript.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/index.js:63:23) at compileScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/command.js:265:29) at compilePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/command.js:220:14) at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/command.js:141:20) at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/bin/coffee:15:45) at Module._compile (module.js:569:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10) at Module.load (module.js:503:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10) at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16) at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

What am i doing wrong?

---

### UPDATE:

As per James note i'm now sending a "hex" string to my decrypt function:

```
crypto    = require('crypto')
algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'
password  = 'test'

fs = require 'fs'

decrypt = (text) ->
  decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password)
  dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8')
  dec

file = fs.readFileSync './test.env.encrypted'

console.log decrypt file.toString('hex')
```

But then it's yielding a new error:

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipher.final (crypto.js:181:26)
    at decrypt (/Users/h/tmp/encrypt_test/test.coffee:12:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/h/tmp/encrypt_test/test.coffee:17:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/h/tmp/encrypt_test/test.coffee:1:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.CoffeeScript.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/index.js:63:23)
    at compileScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/command.js:265:29)
    at compilePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/command.js:220:14)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/command.js:141:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/bin/coffee:15:45)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

File was encrypted using:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -e -in test.env -out test.env.encrypted
```

with

```
test
```

as password

Comment: A lot of good hits for ["openssl aes-256-cbc" "node.js"](https://www.google.com/search?q="openssl+aes-256-cbc"+"node.js"). Six of the top eight are Stack Overflow questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `decipher.update` expects a `hex` encoded string but you're passing a `utf-8` string.

Either change your `readFileSync` to read with `hex` encoding or change the `update` call to expect `utf-8` input.

Comment: good catch, but now it's yielding a different error! i can feel it's almost there, i updated my question to reflect you suggestion

Comment: @kroe is your encrypted file definitely hex?

Comment: i reckon is utf8, but using utf8 instead of hex it yields error: Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length

Comment: @kroe sounds like an issue with your key, have a look at [this article](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2794).